# How to build a custom printing service on android

Tags: android, printing

I'm working on an Android app, I need to find a way to print a pdf from the app using a specific printer Lexmark model, the question I have is, if there is a way to write a printer service in order to don't use the one from the play store (like this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexmark.print&hl=en_US&gl=US)?.

I'm looking for it because the devices we're using don't connect to the Google Play Store (they have their own store), also I'm not allow to install any other apk (like the service) to the device, so that's why I need an own printer service.

Thank you!!

Comment: Unclear if you have seen: https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/AndroidCupsPrint

Comment: I know is better to use the manufacturers drivers, the problem is I can't use them, the device I'm using is a POS, I'm not allow to install not allowed apps, the drivers are not allowed, about cups, is another way but for now I'm looking if there is any way to write a printer driver (Lexmark to be more specific) on android.